# tail -f, insert line break after log is idle for 3 seconds?

Tags: linux, bash

*Edit :*

I later posted this question on the correct  [place : stackexchange site only for Linux/Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425885/tail-f-insert-line-break-after-log-is-idle-for-3-seconds)

*:EndEdit*

When doing a `tail -f error.log`, how to insert programmatically a line break after nothing has been appened to the file for 3 seconds ?

(obviously, once one line break has been added, no other line break should be added until other line(s) of text is added to the log file)

For instance, these lines are appened to error.log :

```
foo
bar
boo [[wait 4 seconds]]
2far
2foo
2bar
2boo [[wait 40 seconds]]
2far
```

Where [[wait X seconds]] is the delay from the next line to be appened (this is NOT part of the input text)

This would be the output in the console :

```
foo
bar
boo

2far
2foo
2bar
2boo

2far
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a self-confessed cross-site duplicate,

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice. I do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r line;do n=$(date +%s); [ $nn -lt $(( n - 3 )) ] && echo ; nn=$n;  echo $line;  done < <(tail -f /path/to/somelogfile)
```

Here, the output of the 'tail -f' command is passed to the while loop using [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).
The while loop reads the output of tail line by line and prints it, while maintaining the timestamp of the time when it last read a line. It prints an empty line if the last saved timestamp is more than 3 seconds ago. Note that the empty line will be printed at a time just before the next line is printed, not immediately after 3 seconds is elapsed from the last update.